# midl error 2025 when compiling idl file on win32 (midl doesn't like string<40>)

Tags: c++, idl, ace, tao, ace-tao

The idl files I have compile fine with linux tools, but when I try to compile using midl I get an error

```
error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a declarator or * near "<"
```

the line is:

```
typedef string<40>      somestring;
```

Is this non-standard idl, or am I missing something?  Is there a switch for midl to allow this?

I wish I could set the bounty on this sooner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake.  It is ACE/TAO specific.  there is a tao_idl.exe idl compiler/processor.  I will tag this question with ACE TAO